# ansible - Wait until server/api/doc is online

Tags: ansible

Folks,
I am trying to poll a ReST api from a Server I have deployed with ansible. I wanna archive to query the ReST api and see it is online before I am starting with other ReST Calls.
Therefor I have ansible running here on my latest Macbook and am trying to archive this with:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

      vars:
        DDVE_public_IP: 34.107.103.175
        destination_port: 3009
        Instance_id: 8529834022607504819
        S3_bucket_name: bucket_for_ddve_6
    
      tasks:
        - name: Wait until {{ DDVE_public_IP }}/api/doc is comming online
          uri:
             url: https://{{ DDVE_public_IP }}/api/doc
             status_code: 200
             method: GET
          register: _result
          until: _result.status == 200
          retries: 720 # 720 * 5 seconds = 1hour (60*60/5)
          delay: 5 # Every 5 seconds
```

What I am getting is:

```
    ❯ ansible-playbook ddve6-post-deploy-object-store.yml
    [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
    [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /Users/juergen/Documents/DPSCodeAcademy/Ansible/#dev/ddve/ddve6-post-deploy-object-store.yml, line 25, column
    9, found a duplicate dict key (body). Using last defined value only.

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Wait until 34.107.103.175/api/doc is comming online] ************************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Wait until 34.107.103.175/api/doc is comming online (720 retries left).
```

While a https:// with exact the same url is giving me back a 200 and is working an showing result.
What do I have to change so my ansible is moving on to the next step? Anything wrong with my macbook?
❯ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.3
python version = 3.9.1

Comment: Two things: you'll want to increase the ansible-playbook verbosity to see what it **is** giving back, and you'll want to include in your question how you exercised "exact the same url" since the details matter (and we can't guess them)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from the certificate from the htpps page. By adding validate_certs: false I got it going.

> - name: Wait until {{ DDVE_public_IP }}/api/doc is comming online
>   uri:
>   validate_certs: false
>   url: https://{{ DDVE_public_IP }}/api/doc
>   status_code: 200
>   method: GET
>   register: _result
>   until: _result.status == 200
>   retries: 720 # 720 * 5 seconds = 1hour (60*60/5)
>   delay: 5 # Every 5 seconds

did the job !!